# FOSRestBundle get datas from ManyToMany/One field during a POST request

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using FOSRestBundle and I trying to post a new `server` in my DB

I have my server entity with `ManyToMany` and `OneToMany` references

```
// SERVER ENTITY

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $name;

// OTHER SIMPLE FIELD

/**
 * @var Os
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Os", inversedBy="servers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $os;

/**
 * @var ServiceIp[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ServiceIp", mappedBy="server")
 */
private $serviceIps;
```

I have made a `postAction` in my **API** `ServerController`

```
// $server is the request body
public function postAction(Server $server, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if ($validationErrors->count() > 0) {
        return $this->handleBodyValidationErrorsView($validationErrors);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($server);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->view($server);
}
```

I send a POST request with JSON body to set new datas

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "os": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I send this request the `os` is null

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "test",
    "os": {
        "id": null,
        "slug": null,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

This action work with simple field like `name` but not with complex one.

How can I get the current `os` values with the `id` set in my body before the request ?
This the good way to make it ?

Thanks for your help.